# How to make Navigation and return system?

Tags: navigation, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello there!

I am working with turtlebot3 waffle and i try to make Navigation and return system.
Obviously i can do navigation with turtlebot3 in a map which is from SLAM, but i want turtlebot3 to move where i pointed and return to the initial position.
Do you understand what I mean?

i have no idear please help me out

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280081/how-to-make-navigation-and-return-system?/) by [par8057](https://answers.ros.org/users/31953/par8057/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-01-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A good place to start is [the navigation tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation/Tutorials).

In the future, you can search the site with Google using the following terms:

```
<question> site:answers.ros.org
```

Where `<question>` is your question. This has been asked many times.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2018-01-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1